# Generating a Cylindrical Surface with np.outer

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, coordinates, surface

I was able to previously generate and plot a spherical surface using np.outer:

```
u = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = R * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = R * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
```

where x, y, z are of dim 100 x 100.
See figure for result and ignore "particle traces"
[image]

I understand the math and direction cosines of a sphere as well as cylinder so I think the confusion comes from not understanding what exactly np.outer is doing.

I would expect that the following would generate a cylinder:

```
u = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
h = 5
x = R * np.cos(u)                 
y = R * np.sin(u)                 
z = np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u))
```

but when I try to plot, nothing is generated and I believe it is due to the discrepancy in array dimensions: (100,).
See Figure for result.
[image]

The other thing I tried was this:

```
u = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
h = 5
x = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(u))                                     
y = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.sin(u))                                     
z = np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u)) * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.ones(np.size(u)))
```

See figure for result.
[image]

I don't understand why I can't get this to work. 
Other notes:
- Clearly this is only for the lateral surface of the cylinder so if there is any way to generate the top/bottom surfaces in the same x, y, z that would be ideal
- This code must work independently of matplotlib as the points themselves are also essential
- If this accomplishable with np.outer, this would also be ideal

I appreciate any help in advance.

EDIT:

How, then, could I generate the top and bottom surfaces?
Would it not be?:

```
x = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(u))
y = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.sin(u))
z = h * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.ones(np.size(u)))
```

This gives me no result as before.

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to plot and the specific error?

Comment: @Grr Please see edits, note that for graphing I am using the python Plotly API so I am not sure that my results will help someone who doesn't understand Plotly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
u = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
h = 5
x = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(u))                                     
y = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.sin(u))                                     
z = np.outer(np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u)), np.ones(np.size(u)))
```

Also, check the [docs on `np.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) if you are unsure what it does. It simply take the outer product of two vectors and produces a matrix.

Comment: ahh I see, I thought i tried this but it does work, thanks

Comment: How, then, could I generate the top and bottom surfaces? See edit

Answer (score 1):

Given you example you can create a plot in the following fashion:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

R = 2
u = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = R * np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = R * np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x,y,z)
fig.show()
```

This produces the following figure, basically the same as what you show in your edit:
[image]

The second and third bits of code are actually producing what appears to be a minimal representation of a cylinder. I will skip the code, but both produce the following:
[image]

It is important to note however, that the second bit of code produces `x`, `y`, and `z` with shapes `(100,)` while the third bit produces shapes `(100,100)`, but the entries on the second dimension are all just repeats and equal to the values from the second bit of code. For example:

```
u = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
h = 5
x = R * np.cos(u)                 
y = R * np.sin(u)                 
z = np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u))  

u2 = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
h2 = 5
x2 = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(u))                                     
y2 = R * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.sin(u))                                     
z2 = np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u)) * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.ones(np.size(u)))

print(np.all(x2 == x))
True
print(np.all(y2 == y))
True
print(np.all(z2 == z))
True
```

So it would seem that the problem is that you are not correctly constructing the surface. When I am constructing a surface I do so with[`numpy.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html). For your example I would do the following:

```
u = np.linspace(0,  2*np.pi, 100)
h = 5
R = 2
z = np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u))
us, zs = np.meshgrid(u, z)
xs = R * np.cos(us)
ys = R * np.cos(us)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xs,ys,zs)
```

You will get the following figure:

[image]

The difference between the two methods rests only in the values of `z` and `zs`. You will find that taking the transpose of `z` is equal to `zs` so to fix you code just change:

```
z = np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u)) * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.ones(np.size(u)))
```

to:

```
z = (np.linspace(0, h, np.size(u)) * np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.ones(np.size(u)))).T
```

And all should be well.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of what was happening, I was indeed confused and this was an excellent clarification.