# How to do a 3D circle in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I am a beginner in Python. I'm trying to plot a circle using matplotlib that has tangent to Z axis. I know how to draw a sphere in 3D but don't know how to draw a circle/ring in 3D plot. Can someone help me with the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Draw flat objects in 3D plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/pathpatch3d.html), [Python 2D circular surface in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43925577/1782792).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the usual imports, plus the 3D toolkit

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

You need a 3D enabled `axes` object

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
```

You need a circle, contained in the plane *y-z*

```
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 201)
y = 10*np.cos(theta)
z = 10*np.sin(theta)
```

Now we can plot the original circle and, as an example, a number of circles rotated about the *z*-axis and whose centers are also placed at a fixed distance (equal to the circle's radius) from the *z*-axis, so that they are tangent to it

```
for i in range(18):
    phi = i*np.pi/9
    ax.plot(y*np.sin(phi)+10*np.sin(phi),
            y*np.cos(phi)+10*np.cos(phi), z)
```

eventually we place a vertical axis and a legend

```
ax.plot((0,0),(0,0), (-10,10), '-k', label='z-axis')
ax.legend()
```

It's time to see what we got

```
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help and time. Could you please help me to solve out one more question? I have also posted the question. You can click on the link to go to that question.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/56868672/11728630

Comment: @HirenGadhiya I have updated my answer because I have _already_ found your other question... I hope that my answer is more close to what you've really asked. —  I will comment on the other question but I'm not going to answer because I think it's quite off-topic wrt programming. Ciao.

Comment: I got a possibly well deserved downvote and  so I ask _"How could I improve my answer?"_

Answer (score 3):

**`mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d`**

https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/mplot3d/pathpatch3d.html was [mentioned
in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870675/how-to-do-a-3d-circle-in-matplotlib#comment100290473_56870675), the example can be minimized to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Draw a circle on the x=0 'wall'
p = Circle((5, 5), 3)
ax.add_patch(p)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(p, z=0, zdir="x")

ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_zlim(0, 10)

plt.show()
```

which gives:

[image]

This is a bit nicer than https://stackoverflow.com/a/56871467/895245 as it uses a higher level `Circle` object directly, instead of requiring you to explicitly plot the lines.

Unfortunately, 3D support in matplotlib is a bit limited as mentioned in the documentation itself, and you have to do some extra work to plot on planes not parallel to the main coordinate plane: [How can matplotlib 2D patches be transformed to 3D with arbitrary normals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228966/how-can-matplotlib-2d-patches-be-transformed-to-3d-with-arbitrary-normals)

Tested on matplotlib==3.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know how to draw a circle/ring in 3D plot.  I'm trying to plot a circle that has tangent to Z axis

You can either

- use a [Circle patch](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html). This should be the best solution, but it doesn't work very well in some configurations (e.g. it throws an error when the figure has a `constrained` layout)
- use discrete points with individual (x,y,z) triplets, linked by a line. Just set one of the coordinate constant to project a flat circle onto that axis. This is the method used in the currently selected answer.

While the latter method is not intellectually optimal, it is a workable bypass for the problems with `Circle`. However iterating over all individual points can be slow when using a Python loop. The variant in this answer speeds up and allows for more concise code using numpy array operations directly, instead of Python loops.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

r = 2 # desired radius
n = 100 # number of points for the circle
x,y,z = 12, 56, 20 # circle center

# Get circle discrete points in z-plane
# Convert to Cartesian coordinates
# Set the 3rd coordinate to a fixed value
points = r*np.exp(1j*np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n))
u,v = np.real(points), np.imag(points)
w = np.repeat(r, n)

# Set pyplot configuration
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')

# To plot one circle, just use:
#ax.plot (u+x,v+y,w+z)

# ---------------------------------------------

# # Fancy plot of circles at different locations
from itertools import permutations
perms = set(permutations([0,1,2])).union(permutations([0,1,3]))

coords = [u,v,w,-w]
for idx, idy, idz in perms: ax.plot(coords[idx]+x, coords[idy]+y, coords[idz]+z)
```